# SPARK uses only one Virtual Core on each machine in cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

It seems that when I run the spark application in YARN, it only uses 1 core on each machine. How to make it use all the cores on the machine ?

My yarn-site.xml is:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>57344</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>5</value>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>30</value>
</property>
```

And my spark-defaults.conf has the following:

```
spark.driver.memory=8g
spark.driver.cores=3
spark.executor.memory=48g
spark.executor.cores=30
```

When I do "htop", it shows a lot of cores being used. But in the yarn webUI, I see only 1 vCore used.

[image]

Comment: I application running in yarn-cluster or client mode?

Comment: Using spark 1.6 with yarn-cluster mode

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out what was missing.

The spark-defaults.conf requires these two lines:

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true
```

The above should be used if you are using Spark 1.4 and above (I am not sure about 1.3). For older versions of spark:

```
spark.executor.instances=15
```

should be used.

Comment: I've added these lines in spark-defaults.conf (spark 1.4), but It still uses only 1 vcore per node. Should I restart yarn or spark master, slave nodes? Thnx!

Comment: Try the restart on yarn, and spark. If that does not work, you may need to look into other applications you are using on the cluster. For me, another issue was some of the settings in hive were also messing up spark runs.